# How to unhide Visual Studio extension errors?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

How do i un-hide errors loading extension in Visual Studio?

That is, if i click **No** on the following dialog:

[image]

How do i undo that click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following command-line will "un-hide" all load errors:

```
devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs
```

From [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276.aspx):

> Clears all options to skip loading added to VSPackages by users wishing to avoid loading problem VSPackages, then starts Visual Studio.
>
> The presence of a SkipLoading tag disables the loading of a VSPackage; clearing the tag re-enables the loading of the VSPackage.

Comment: I'm not going to test it (since if you're wrong i'll never be able to see the warnings again). But it sounds reasonable.

Comment: I am pretty sure that I have already used this command successfully, but that was several months ago and with VS2010, that is why I have used a "cautious wording".